# How do I append text to a file on a Web server?

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal

I am using Lazarus 1.0.8 (latest version) and I have installed Indy 10. I also have a website with a PHP script that saves on the server a text file (called "stats.txt"). I would like, using my program, to upload another text file that contains stats' text + the new text I have wrote in a memo. I don't want ask you to write the code for me, just could you give me a suggestion about how could I do it?

I was thinking that I could download the content of "stats.txt" on a memo and then, upload this again but adding the new text. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you asking also how to do the server part, or only the client?

Comment: No, I only need to know how to upload a text file basically. I've just downloaded Indy, so I wanted a suggestion

Comment: Dont listen to them :p They do suggest POST method because they do not know about the right tool - PUT method :)

Comment: Who are you referring to as "them," @User539484? Surely not I, who clearly demonstrated awareness of the PUT method. Using it will require the server offering that method, though, which isn't as prevalent as GET and POST. As I said in my answer, it really all depends on what the server allows.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, yet you started with POST speculation. PUT is baseline HTTP. OP's requirement is suboptimal but pretty clear: get a **file**, process it, and then put it back.

Comment: I've just installed Delphi XE4, the latest version, so I have Indy correctly installed. Of course I have problems here too, this time my problem is that the IDE says "Cannot resolve unit name xxx". All units are underlined in red. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's not the same problem you had with Lazarus, Alberto? You need to make sure you configure the IDE to know what directory you have the Indy DCUs installed in. This has nothing to do with how to upload text files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on what capabilities the server offers. If the server has some sort of "append" command, you could issue a request with that command and the new text, and let the server update its data. Check the documentation for the server software.

It might offer a URL that you can send data to using a POST command. Indy's `TIdHTTP` component has a `Post` method; you can provide the URL and the text data, and it will take care of establishing the HTTP connection, sending the data, and interpreting any response.

---

If the server only offers ways to query the entire text and receive the entire text, then you have no choice but to do what's described in the question: Download all the data, modify it locally, and then update the server.

Fetching the current version of the data will probably involve a GET request. Indy's `TIdHTTP` component offers several `Get` methods that take a URL and return data, either in a string or a stream.

Once you've modified your data, you will probably find you can issue a POST request, or maybe PUT, and include the updated data.

Answer (score 2):

The question has two parts here:  how do you upload a file over HTTP, and how do you accomplish that with Lazarus?  Let's take them one at a time.

You upload a file with HTTP by sending a POST request and encoding the file with MIME multipart form encoding.  This is a special protocol that's designed specifically for uploading files over HTTP, and it's what the server will expect.

So, how do you set up a HTTP request with multipart form encoding?  You said you're using Indy 10, so have a look at the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` class, in the `IdMultipartFormData` unit.  It should be simple enough once you've looked over the class's interface, and there's an overload of the `TidHTTP.Post()` method that accepts a `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` object as input.

Comment: My problem is that when I put for example IdStream in the uses, or any else indy libraby, I have an error from lazarus. Do you think I have to reinstall the package?

Comment: Without more information than "I have an error from Lazarus" I really can't answer that.

Comment: Yes sorry. The IDE says to me "Can not find unit IdStream used by Unit1."

Comment: @Alberto: Then you need to check your search paths.  That means that the compiler isn't looking in the folder that contains `IdStream`.

Comment: Using MIME with POST is not the only way to upload files.  HTTP also has a PUT command as well.

Comment: @Remy: OK, and how do you PUT a file on a server with Indy?

Comment: @Mason I did what you said, I've changed the folder and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Indy's `TIdHTTP` component has separate `Get()`, `Post()`, and `Put()` methods for HTTP `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` requests, respectively.